# I can't get a .net webservice working on an iPad

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ios, ajax

I have a simple webservice in .net

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string EnableRetailer(int ID)
    {
        var result = Business.Business.EnableRetailer(ID);
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

And I'm trying to post to this method using jquery with this code

```
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/api/BoothWebService.asmx/EnableRetailer",
                    data: { ID: '2965' },
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
        });
```

It works on every single browser on my computer, but I get an "internal error" on the iPad.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is the service running on the same machine as your browsers?

Comment: Yes, the service is running on the same machine as the browsers.

Comment: seems like you may be trying to hit a local url from your ipad. Can you tell what the full path of the url is in your ajax call? i.e.: with the http prefix etc

Comment: good call, it's not working from a second machine.  Although I don't understand the question.  It seems to be hitting the webservice itself since I'm getting an "internal error" and not a "not found" error.  Perhaps it's a security issue?

Comment: @Javalsu, can you ping the root domain name of the URL from another machine?

Comment: It could be a security issue. Have you tried checking the web server logs?

Comment: Yes, the webservice is being called by the same .net website.  It's for clientside data.

Comment: @Javalsu, how is the web service hosted?

Comment: It's part of the .net website.  So it's published along with the same site that's calling it.  Hosted in IIS7.

Comment: have you tried pinging as per Michael's suggestion?

Comment: It turns out that I had to change the data from an object to a string.  I have no idea why that worked but it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason passing an object as the data only worked when I was on the same machine as it was hosted on.  I had to change the ajax call to the following for it to work.

```
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "../api/BoothWebService.asmx/EnableRetailer",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "{ 'ID': " + ID + " }",
                async: false,
            });
```